# SerialPort.ReadByte all of a sudden returns zero in stead of the version number of the attached cable

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, windows-10

We use a USB to SerialPort converter for a long time now in our application. To check if the correct cable is attached we start with sending a command that requests the converter to return its version. We then read te returned data using

```
var version=SerialPort.ReadByte();
```

Which is expected to return &11 for version 1.1.
All of a sudden on Windows 10 1803 or later versions this checks starts to fail because `ReadByte()` returns first a zero then, when called a second time, &11.

This change in behaviour must be caused by a Windows update as we did not change this part of the code in years.
Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on? Is this a Windows 10 fluke that will be reversed soon, or is our implementation inherently wrong?

**EDIT**

I replaced `ReadByte()` with `ReadExisting()` and that came back with (in VB.Net) vbNullChar & vbNullChar & CharW(17).

So it seems that the first call to `ReadByte` returns the two nullchars and the second call returns the expected value of &11

**EDIT**
There is another, very likely cause as well: the two converters we used to test are from the same batch. They seemingly respond with two null chars the first time they are read.

Comment: _"This change in behaviour must be caused by a Windows update"_ -- that's the wrong way to look at it. It is entirely possible that _the bug in your code_ or the _the bug in your device_ was not apparent until something changed in a recent Windows update. But the likelihood of the Windows update itself _causing_ the bug is remote. Assuming a properly configured serial port, .NET is not going to return different bytes than what are sent by the device. I put my money on _"[your] implementation is inherently wrong"_.

Comment: What usb to rs232 converters do you use? Do you need drivers for them and if so are those up to date?

Comment: @B.Letz We use the ATEN USB to Serial converter https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/usb-&-thunderbolt/usb-converters/uc232a/
We are testing the newest drivers right now. The problem seems to be with certain batch of these cables together with the Windows 10 drivers we advise for them. On other Os's the problem does not occur.